# Unable to move image in app

Tags: android

I am developing hunting game, for that i have to move the gun in horizontal direction
I can display the gun but, am unable to move the gun. For motion I have taken `ontouchlistener` but am not able to move :

```
public class Touchmoveimage extends Activity {

    int x,y,x1,y1;

    RelativeLayout rl;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bb);

    x = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    y = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    final ImageView balls = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ball);

    balls.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 

    {


   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 

                  {

                        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)

                        {
                            x1=(int) event.getX();

                            y1=(int) event.getY();

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param=new        
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(x1,y1);

                                 rl.addView(balls, param);
                        }
                        return false;

                    }
    }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use a SurfaceView instead. A fine example how to use this is the Lunar Lander in the Android SDK examples.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? "A fine example how to use this is the Lunar Lander in the Android SDK examples."

Comment: What you want to do is not achievable with less code. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html is a good place to read up on what the SurfaceView is and how to use it. Lunar Lander uses the SurfaceView and also a thread that does the calculations and draw. So in onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) you check if the Event is ACTION_DOWN you set a boolean to true and you start the render thread. It also updates the X and Y and you draw. ACTION_UP sets the boolean to false and stops the render thread. Or you may choose to modify it to your liking.